# Shared variable in python's multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

First question is what is the difference between Value and Manager().Value?

Second, is it possible to share integer variable without using Value?
Below is my sample code. What I want is getting a dict with a value of integer, not Value. What I did is just change it all after the process. Is there any easier way?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def f(n):
    n.value += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = {}
    p = []

    for i in range(5):
        d[i] = Manager().Value('i',0)
        p.append(Process(target=f, args=(d[i],)))
        p[i].start()

    for q in p:
        q.join()

    for i in d:
        d[i] = d[i].value

    print d
```

Comment: Relevant: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing

Answer (score 71, accepted):

When you use [`Value`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) you get a [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) object in shared memory that by default is synchronized using [`RLock`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.RLock).  When you use [`Manager`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) you get a [`SynManager`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager) object that controls a server process which allows object values to be manipulated by other processes.  You can create multiple proxies using the same manager; there is no need to create a new manager in your loop:

```
manager = Manager()
for i in range(5):
    new_value = manager.Value('i', 0)
```

The `Manager` can be shared across computers, while `Value` is limited to one computer.  `Value` will be faster (run the below code to see), so I think you should use that unless you need to support arbitrary objects or access them over a network.

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Value


def foo(data, name=''):
    print(type(data), data.value, name)
    data.value += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = Manager()
    x = manager.Value('i', 0)
    y = Value('i', 0)

    for i in range(5):
        Process(target=foo, args=(x, 'x')).start()
        Process(target=foo, args=(y, 'y')).start()

    print('Before waiting: ')
    print('x = {0}'.format(x.value))
    print('y = {0}'.format(y.value))

    time.sleep(5.0)
    print('After waiting: ')
    print('x = {0}'.format(x.value))
    print('y = {0}'.format(y.value))
```

**To summarize:**

1. Use `Manager` to create multiple shared objects, including dicts and
   lists.  Use `Manager` to share data across computers on a network.
2. Use `Value` or `Array` when it is not necessary to share information
   across a network and the types in `ctypes` are sufficient for your
   needs.
3. `Value` is faster than `Manager`.

**Warning**

By the way, sharing data across processes/threads should be avoided if possible.  The code above will probably run as expected, but increase the time it takes to execute `foo` and things will get weird.  Compare the above with:

```
def foo(data, name=''):
    print type(data), data.value, name
    for j in range(1000):
        data.value += 1
```

You'll need a `Lock` to make this work correctly.

I am not especially knowledgable about all of this, so maybe someone else will come along and offer more insight.  I figured I would contribute an answer since the question was not getting attention.

Comment: can we add any value to Array? I can't append any value to Array.

Comment: @user2435611, [`Array`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array) will give you a shared ctypes array.  You need to decide what type of data you are storing beforehand, and supply a [type code](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#module-array).  For example, `a = Array('c', 10)` creates an array of one-character strings of length 10.  New entries can be added to the array like so: `a[0] = 'b'`.  You cannot add *any* value to an array, see [the list of type codes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#module-array).

Comment: So we should decide the size of array beforehand and can't expand it? if so, it's better for me to use manager.list(). Thanks for help :)

Comment: @user2435611: Yes, I think that's right.  The `multiprocessing.Array` is allocated memory at the time of creation and unlike `array.array` cannot be expanded.  Use `manager.list` if you really have no idea how much space you need, but you might want to experiment with allocating an `Array` with some extra space if you can find an upper-bound on the size.  I hope that helps.

Comment: @ChrisP i'm late to the party, but how would you recommend sharing a simple int variable across processes on one machine?  I use multiprocessing for IO bound workers (until I learn async), and would like to have a counter they share so I know how many iterations they've gone through.  Recs on how best to implement?

Comment: @TravisLeleu did you find a solution for this?

Comment: How about sharing data by adding it to other module and accessing that module from all processes something explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701273/sharing-common-and-worker-specific-information-across-workers-and-modules-in-pyt)? This does not at all use any features of multiprocessing module, but plain python. Is this ok, if I dont want to have synchronized access?

Comment: Can you just comment if we can share any datatype such as pandas dataframe using this approach?

Comment: You should use a `Lock` to protect `Value`, see https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing

Comment: it seems that it does not run fo py3

Comment: It doesn't work for python3.7: `AttributeError: 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection'`