# python multiprocessing - sharing variables between processes pools

Tags: python, multiprocessing

My program creates two pools:

`file_creator_pool` initialized with `filenum` variable which is stored in global `total_files` to be accessible for all processes in the pool

```
#global
total_files = None

def init_creator_pool(filenum):
    global total_files
    total_files = filenum

filenum = multiprocessing.Manager().Value('i', 0) 
file_creator_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(MAX_PROCESSES, initializer=init_creator_pool, initargs=(filenum,))
```

Now I want total_files be accessible in ranamer_pool as well

```
file_renamer_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(MAX_PROCESSES)
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the same technique you are already using.  Your code seems a bit odd though: it's not clear why you are making a managed value and then passing it as well (the point of managed values is that `multiprocessing` sends them around automatically).  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17393879/1256452 and also http://stackoverflow.com/a/660468/1256452

Comment: @torek Thanks torek, but what do you mean "the same technique"? Do you mean that `filenum` should be visible for `file_renamer_pool` processes anyway? Now about the code, AFAIK it's the way to share share variable among processes in the pool when they're going to access it for writing. Do you mean just crate global managed `filenum` without passing it to Pool ctor?

Comment: If you're changing `filenum` in each Process, yes, you do need something like this, at least on Windows.  (I don't see anything writing new values into `filenum`, but that may just not be visible in your code snippet.)  What I mean by "the same technique" is that you can pass `initializer=` and `initargs=`, yes (perhaps even using the very same function).

Comment: @torek Thanks torek will try. Indeed, processes from `file_creator_pool` do change `filenum` so I have to aquire and release lock on it. This code snippet isn't presented here since I think it not relevant to actual question