# Should I access / share variable of a module in multiple processes created using multiprocessing module

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a requirement, wherein I have keep certain data (which can be anything pandas dataframe or any ML trained model) always available to all daemon processes created using multiprocessing module. Mostly I wont be requiring to modify this data but only use it. Multiprocessing modules provides various mechanisms like `Value`, `Manager` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393879/6357916). Does it makes sense to add such data to the separate module and access it from different processes, instead of using `Value` or `Array`.

**common_data.py** (contains common data to be shared by processes)

```
worker_specific_conf = None
common_conf = None
list = [1,2,3]
```

**libX.py** (contains functions which simply prints info from `common_data.py`)

```
import common_data as cmn
from posix import getpid

def functionX():
    print(str(getpid()) + " : " + str(cmn.worker_specific_conf) + " : " + str(cmn.common_conf))

def functionY():
    print(str(getpid()) + " : " + str(cmn.worker_specific_conf) + " : " + str(cmn.common_conf))

def functionList():
    print(str(getpid()) + " : " + str(cmn.worker_specific_conf) + " : " + str(cmn.list))

def functionDf():
    print(str(getpid()) + " : " + str(cmn.worker_specific_conf) + " : " + str(cmn.df))
```

**workers.py** (Run this, it creates multiple workers which access data from `common_data.py` using `libX.py`)

```
import uuid
import libX
import multiprocessing as mu
from time import sleep
import common_data as cmn #
from random import random
import pandas as pd

def worker(a):
    #global my_id  
    sleep(random())
    cmn.worker_specific_conf = uuid.uuid4() # 
    #my_id= uuid.uuid4()
    libX.functionX()
    sleep(random())
    libX.functionY()
    sleep(random())
    libX.functionList()
    sleep(random())
    libX.functionDf()

data = [1,2,3,4,5]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cmn.df = df    #adding data to data sharing module dynamically

cmn.common_conf = random()
cmn.list.append(4)
pool = mu.Pool(processes = 2)
pool.map(worker, range(3))
```

Is this approach ok if I just want to be able to read shared data from different processes?

---

**Output**

```
6732 : d08673d2-1d8f-4f87-b9ad-d1389ea564d6 : 0.3915408966829501
6732 : d08673d2-1d8f-4f87-b9ad-d1389ea564d6 : 0.3915408966829501
6732 : d08673d2-1d8f-4f87-b9ad-d1389ea564d6 : [1, 2, 3, 4]
12152 : af373f13-35b5-47b2-9736-5b19ee028c9c : 0.3915408966829501
6732 : d08673d2-1d8f-4f87-b9ad-d1389ea564d6 :    0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
6732 : c629d9c3-f439-4818-ac79-1340f98470ea : 0.3915408966829501
12152 : af373f13-35b5-47b2-9736-5b19ee028c9c : 0.3915408966829501
12152 : af373f13-35b5-47b2-9736-5b19ee028c9c : [1, 2, 3, 4]
6732 : c629d9c3-f439-4818-ac79-1340f98470ea : 0.3915408966829501
12152 : af373f13-35b5-47b2-9736-5b19ee028c9c :    0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
6732 : c629d9c3-f439-4818-ac79-1340f98470ea : [1, 2, 3, 4]
6732 : c629d9c3-f439-4818-ac79-1340f98470ea :    0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
```

Comment: _"Mostly I wont be requiring to modify this data but only use it."_ Well, when you _do_ modify the data, I don't expect that modification to be visible in any other process. AFAIK, each process gets a completely independent copy. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes for some common approaches to sharing state between processes.

Comment: @Kevin I need different types of data (pandas dataframe, h5 file) to be shared. **Q1.** Is it possible with multiprocessing's `Value`? I felt no. So, I have written [small code](https://pastebin.com/KM5nmkJj). There is a `common_data` module which holds data shared by all daemons. A server listens on port. If it received message starting with `add` it adds random key-value to `common_data.map`. If it received message not starting with `add`, it spawns new daemon. The new daemon will be able to access all key-values added earlier to `common_data.map`.

Comment: [..continued] Now the issue is I have to add key-values on server's main thread. If I add key values in new daemon, other daemon wont be able to access it. **Q3.** Is it because those values become scoped to thread? And **Q4.** Why daemons are able to access values added by server? Is there any work around. **Q5.** Also all those new thread re running common_data.py which can be overhead if there is a lot of data? **Q6.** Is there any other option for my requirement?