# How to keep track of python multiprocessing pool and run a function after every X iteration?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have some simple python multiprocessing code as below:

```
files = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt', etc..]

def convert_file(file):
  do_something(file) 

mypool = Pool(number_of_workers)
mypool.map(convert_file, files)
```

I have 100,000s files to be converted by `convert_file` and would like to run function where I upload every 20 converted files to a server without waiting for all files to be converted. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Are you concerned about the possibility of `do_something` throwing an exception? If so, then you need to be more careful with your processing.

Comment: @Dunes could you further clarify? I don't expect an exception but it is entirely possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With multiprocessing you have a slight problem with how to deal with exceptions that occur within a single job. If you use the `map` variants then you need to be careful in how you poll for results otherwise you might lose some if the `map` function is forced to raise an exception. Further, you won't even know which job was the problem unless you have special handling any any exceptions within your job. If you use the `apply` variants then you don't need to be has careful when getting your results, but collating the results becomes a bit more tricky.

Overall, I think `map` is the easiest to get working though.

First, you need a special exception, which cannot be created in your main module, otherwise Python will have trouble serialising and deserialising it correctly.

eg.

**custom_exceptions.py**

```
class FailedJob(Exception):
    pass
```

**main.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import random

from custom_exceptions import FailedJob


def convert_file(filename):
    # pseudo implementation to demonstrate what might happen
    if filename == 'file2.txt':
        time.sleep(0.5)
        raise Exception
    elif filename =='file0.txt':
        time.sleep(0.3)
    else:
        time.sleep(random.random())
    return filename  # return filename, so we can identify the job that was completed


def job(filename):
    """Wraps any exception that occurs with FailedJob so we can identify which job failed 
    and why""" 
    try:
        return convert_file(filename)
    except Exception as ex:
        raise FailedJob(filename) from ex


def main():
    chunksize = 4  # number of jobs before dispatch
    total_jobs = 20
    files = list('file{}.txt'.format(i) for i in range(total_jobs))

    with Pool() as pool:
        # we use imap_unordered as we don't care about order, we want the result of the 
        # jobs as soon as they are done
        iter_ = pool.imap_unordered(job, files)
        while True:
            completed = []
            while len(completed) < chunksize:
                # collect results from iterator until we reach the dispatch threshold
                # or until all jobs have been completed
                try:
                    result = next(iter_)
                except StopIteration:
                    print('all child jobs completed')
                    # only break out of inner loop, might still be some completed
                    # jobs to dispatch
                    break
                except FailedJob as ex:
                    print('processing of {} job failed'.format(ex.args[0]))
                else:
                    completed.append(result)

            if completed:
                print('completed:', completed)
                # put your dispatch logic here

            if len(completed) < chunksize:
                print('all jobs completed and all job completion notifications'
                   ' dispatched to central server')
                return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried incorporating your code and tried a chunk size of 6 on 14 files. I see the "completed" dispatch twice but then nothing after that... zombie process?

Comment: Your convert_file function might be throwing an instance `BaseException`, which could cause the pool to hang. Try catching `BaseException` instead of `Exception` in `job` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a shared variable across your processes that keeps track of the converted files. You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393879/4141279)

The variable is automatically locked when a process wants to read and write. During the lock all other processes that want to access the variable have to wait. So you can poll the variable in the main loop and check if it is bigger than 20, while the converting-processes keep incrementing the variable. As soon as the value surpasses 20 you reset the value and write the files to your server.

Comment: I looked at the example you provided and tried some versions of it in my test example but it's still not clear how to do this. I receive the error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'XXX' referenced before assignment