# Python pass variable to multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, variables, multiprocessing, global, pool

I been trying to figure out this for ages, but wondering if anyone might know how I can pass the `s` variable to the pool without making it into an argument?

```
import ctypes
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

def worker1(n):
    k = n*3
    print(k)
    print(s)
    # print(ctypes_int.value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # global s
    somelist = [1,2,3]

    # ctypes_int = mp.Value(ctypes.c_wchar_p , "hi")
    s = "TESTING"
    # worker1(1)
    p = mp.Pool(1)
    p.map(worker1,somelist)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
3
6
9
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Users\light\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 10, in worker1
    print(s)
NameError: name 's' is not defined
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\light\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 21, in <module>
    p.map(worker1,somelist)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shared variable in python's multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377426/shared-variable-in-pythons-multiprocessing)

Comment: um I tried it but it didn't work...maybe I did smth wrong? 
    import ctypes
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker1(n):
    k = n*3
    print(k)
    print(s)
    # print(ctypes_int.value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    somelist = [1,2,3]
 
    # ctypes_int = mp.Value(ctypes.c_wchar_p , "hi")
    # s = "TESTING"

    mgr = mp.Manager()
    s = mgr.Value(ctypes.c_wchar_p , "hi")
    print(s.value)
    # worker1(1)
    p = mp.Pool(1)
    p.map(worker1,somelist)

Comment: @user. Could you please update your post?

Comment: @user as your comment below, you have 8 variable. Please, present this on the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your variable along with each item in `somelist`:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker1(p):
    n,s = p
    k = n*3
    print(k)
    print(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    somelist = [1,2,3]

    s = "TESTING"
    p = mp.Pool(1)
    p.map(worker1,[(n,s) for n in somelist])
```

The parameter `(n,s)` gets passed as `p` and I unpack it into `n,s`.

Comment: um it works, but in my actual script I have maybe 8 other variables, would you know if there are any other methods? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the problem. Just list them along-side `s`: `[(n,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8) for ...`

Comment: @quamrana, Thank you for supporting. Your answers are very helpful :)

Comment: There much be a better way. We can't go on making the tuple and unpacking it at the other end.

Comment: Perhaps this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5442981) might help.