# Python multiprocessing - Using shared variables with a manager between threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I am using a `Manager` from pythons `multiprocessing` library. I would like to share variables between threads.

So I have a function and this function uses one such variable internally. Because of python's multiprocessing rules, I need to put the `Manager` and the variables in `if __name__ == '__main__':`. Is there a smart way to still access the variable `status`? Code below:

```py
from multiprocessing import Value, Manager

def first_methode():
    if status.value:
        do_something...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    recording_status = manager.Value(status, False)
    thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=first_methode)
```

This gives me a

```py
NameError: name 'status' is not defined
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're not defining variable `status` anywhere so you can't access it whether it's `multiprocessing` or not. You probably meant `manager.Value("status", False)`, i.e. the literal string `"status"`, not a variable called `status`.

Additionally, take a look at examples in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) and perhaps the code [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377426/shared-variable-in-pythons-multiprocessing) as several other things in your code are off, for example the `Value` object you create should be passed to the subprocess/function as an argument. Otherwise code in the function has no way of telling what `status` is because it's not defined in the function's scope.